# Getting connection timeout error in jmeter distribution testing while clicking remote start all but scripts r working fine normally

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

**Os:Windows**
Machines:vdi, remote machines

Getting connection timeout error in jmeter distribution testing while clicking remote start all but scripts r working fine normally

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're getting connection timeouts between JMeter master and slaves - check your JMeter instances [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

   - JMeter master should be able to connect to the slaves to transfer the [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) to them
   - JMeter slaves should be able to connect to the master to transfer the test results back
2. If you're getting connection timeouts as the result of your [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) it might be the case that your application under test gets overloaded because if you have 100 user in Test Plan and 1 slave - it will kick off 100 users, each additional slave will add 100 more users so if you have 10 slaves it will be 1000 users. Check [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)) to see what is perceived load you generate
3. Invest into learning some English or if you know it better than me consider changing the way you're asking for help b'cause u r not @ Tinder. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  is a very good place to start.